# Strapi V4 - I don't understand how to get information about the user's permissions

Tags: strapi

I don't get it : how do you get the permissions for an authentificated user ?

There is an endpoint `GET /users-permissions/permissions`. If I query it while authentificated, I get a response that contains permissions, eg.

```
"api::playlist": {
            "controllers": {
                "playlist": {
                    "find": {
                        "enabled": false,
                        "policy": ""
                    },
                    "findOne": {
                        "enabled": false,
                        "policy": ""
                    },
                    "create": {
                        "enabled": false,
                        "policy": ""
                    },
                    "update": {
                        "enabled": false,
                        "policy": ""
                    },
                    "delete": {
                        "enabled": false,
                        "policy": ""
                    }
                }
            }
        },
```

So I get a list of permissions.  They all have "enabled":false, which do not match what I defined for my Authentificated role.

[image]

Is there something I don't get ?

Answer (score 0):

I checked the strapi default user-permission` file under node_modules.

(permission controller) PATH - `node_modules\@strapi\plugin-users-permissions\server\services\permission.js`

(permission services) PATH - `node_modules\@strapi\plugin-users-permissions\server\services\permission.js`

I saw that the `getAction() method` **defaultEnable** parameter is set by false.

Also there is another way to get the user's permission by checking the roles under user-permissions.

http://localhost:1337/api/users-permissions/roles/2

(1 - authenticated, 2 public)

[image]

Comment: Does this means that I have to check a role rather than a user to get his permissions ? Seems that this doesn't make sense - why is there an users-permissions/permissions endpoint then ?

Comment: Well, I'm not sure about that, maybe you can ask the strapi team regarding on "users-permissions/permissions endpoint" but based on what I saw under user-permissions (permission.js) it will always return `"enabled": false`.